# A Complete RPN Expr-Eval Program Inside a Tweet? -- "YES WE CAN!", Using LISP

Tags: lisp, eval, common-lisp, rpn

The Program (115 Chars)

```
(defun rpn(e)(let((s()))(dolist(x e)(if(numberp x)(push x s)(push(eval(reverse(list(pop s)(pop s)x)))s)))(car s)))
```

A simple test:

```
CL-USER> (rpn '(1 2 3 * + 4 2 / +))
```

And it returns `9`

Anyone has some good ideas about writing an Infix-to-RPN program inside one single tweet? I failed. I can wrote that one in 235 chars.

Comment: I'd be happier if this question was changed to "Can one ...?" and then put the program in an answer. Right now, this isn't really a question.

Comment: This will definitely be closed unless it follows the guidelines at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24242/acceptable-level-of-code-golf-questions

Answer (score 3):

Here is one in Clojure (88 chars):

```
(defn rpn [& e](reduce #(if (fn? %2)(let [[l r & m]%](cons (%2 r l) m))(cons %2 %))[]e))
```

And the un-golfed version:

```
(defn rpn [& expr]
  (reduce (fn [stack op]
            (if (fn? op)
              (let [[l r & m] stack]
                (cons (op r l) m))
              (cons op stack)))
          []
          expr))
```